# SpringCloudStream 1.2.2 AggregateApplicationBuilder expects binder

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am getting started with cloud stream and seems to be stuck with this problem from last 2 days. Tried different version looked around stackoverflow, but I am not able to get this working.

Here is my configuration

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Dalston.SR1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>           
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Here is my Aggregator

```
new AggregateApplicationBuilder(AggregateConfig.class)
    .from(JSONFileSourceApplication.class).args("--fixedDelay=10000")
    .via(ProcessorApplicationOne.class)
    .via(ProcessorApplicationTwo.class)
    .via(ProcessorApplicationThree.class)
    .to(LoggingSinkApplication.class).run(args);
```

All my processors are in the below format

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class ProcessorApplicationXXX {

@Transformer(inputChannel = "input", outputChannel = "output")
public String transform(String payload) {

}
}
```

Here is my SourceApplication.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class JSONFileSourceApplication {

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(Source.OUTPUT)
public String greet() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("input_event.json");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    final String jsonRequest = IOUtils.toString(fis);
    return jsonRequest;
}
```

}

If I annotate @Bean on source method, it throws below exception. The examples in the reference documentation are annotated with @Bean. Not sure what I am missing.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'interface org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter' on @Bean method level is allowed only for: org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSourcebeans: java.lang.String
at org.springframework.util.Assert.instanceCheckFailed(Assert.java:389)
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:327)
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.InboundChannelAdapterAnnotationPostProcessor.createMessageSource(InboundChannelAdapterAnnotationPostProcessor.java:85)
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.InboundChannelAdapterAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcess(InboundChannelAdapterAnnotationPostProcessor.java:63)
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor$1.doWith(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:189)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:530)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:537)
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:155)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
... 17 common frames omitted
```

If I take off @Bean, it throws below exception.

```
2017-06-09 19:47:24 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - 
Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: A default binder has been requested, but there there is no binder available
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.aggregate.AggregateApplicationUtils.createParentContext(AggregateApplicationUtils.java:52)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.aggregate.AggregateApplicationBuilder.run(AggregateApplicationBuilder.java:207)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.aggregate.AggregateApplicationBuilder$AppConfigurer.run(AggregateApplicationBuilder.java:412)
at com.xdmodules.aggregate.SampleAggregateApplication.main(SampleAggregateApplication.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A default binder has been requested, but there there is no binder available
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:95)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.getBinder(BindingService.java:155)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:111)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.bindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:238)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:57)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173)
... 16 common frames omitted
```

Please help me with this.

Update:
I ripped off all the business logic/dependencies and created a bare minimum application. I stopped seeing the errors. The application works perfect if there is Source->Processor->Sink. But if there are more than 1 processor, the output is not as expected. May be my channel configuration is wrong or is it related to this issue - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/1519

Here is the link to my sample code.
https://github.com/kkirankulkarni/PlainAggregateApplication

Answer (score 0):

The `@Bean` annotation should not be present on the method, unless the return type is a `MessageSource` - this is a mistake in the documentation - see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/987.

It's unclear why this is failing and parts of the example (e.g. the sink) are missing - could you possibly include a complete example in GitHub ?

You can take a look at this working example too: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/double

Generally speaking, having your full project available should help diagnosing the issue.

Comment: I stopped seeing the errors. The application works perfect if there is Source->Processor->Sink. But if there are more than 1 processor, the output is not as expected. May be my channel configuration is wrong or is it related to this issue - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/1519

Here is the link to my sample code. https://github.com/kkirankulkarni/PlainAggregateApplication

Comment: If you're using `@SpringBootApplication`, you must configure each processor/application in a separate package, otherwise the classpath scanning will cause them to interfere. See the note in http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-cloud-stream-docs/Chelsea.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#_aggregation